# Record not getting updated

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I am new to Ext js, using Extjs 4.1.1. I am trying to update a record(User - model) by editing(View- Edit.js) it. But when the request is sent, operation is being aborted in the mid and not getting completed.
Is extra code to be written to save or there is some flaw in my code?

Please find my code below.

**app.js**

```
    Ext.application({

name: 'AM',

appFolder:'app',

controllers:['Users'],

requires:['AM.view.user.List','AM.Configuration'],

launch:function(){

    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport',{
        layout:'fit',
        items:[{
                xtype:'userlist',
                title:'Users',
                html:'List of users will go here'
            }   
        ]
    });
}});
```

**Model**

```
Ext.define('AM.model.User',{
extend:'Ext.data.Model',
fields: ['id','name','email']});
```

**Store**

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Users',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'AM.model.User',
autoLoad: true,
idProperty:'id',

proxy:{
    type:'ajax',
    url: 'data/users.json',
    api:{
        read: 'data/users.json',
        update: 'data/updateUsers.json'
    },
    reader:{
        type: 'json',
        root: 'users',
        successProperty:'success',
    }   
}});
```

**View**

```
    Ext.define('AM.view.user.Edit',{

extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

alias: 'widget.useredit',

title: 'Edit User',

layout:'fit',

autoShow:'true',

initComponent: function(){

        this.items = [{

                    xtype:'form',
                    items:[{
                        xtype:'textfield',
                        name: 'name',
                        fieldLabel: 'Name'
                    },{
                        xtype:'textfield',
                        name: 'email',
                        fieldLabel: 'Email'
                    }]
            }];

        this.buttons = [{
                text:'Save',
                action:'save'
            },{
                text:'Cancel',
                scope:this,
                handler: this.close
        }]

    this.callParent(arguments);
}});
```

**Controller**

```
    Ext.define('AM.controller.Users',{
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

views:['AM.view.user.List','AM.view.user.Edit'],

requires:['AM.view.user.List'],

stores:['Users'],

models:['User'],

init: function(){
    console.log('Initialized Users!! This happens before the application launch function is called');   
    this.control({

        'userlist':{
             itemdblclick: this.onEditUser
        },
        'useredit button[action=save]':{
            click: this.updateUser
        }

    });
},

onEditUser: function(grid,record){
    console.log('called on Edit User.. for user '+record.get('name'));
    var view = Ext.widget('useredit');
    view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
},

updateUser: function(button){
    console.log('Clcked save button');
    var win = button.up('window'),
    form = win.down('form'),
    record = form.getRecord(),
    values = form.getValues();

    record.set(values);
    win.close();
    this.getUsersStore().sync();
}});
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'in the mid' ? Where did you stuck?

Comment: @sra: on saving, I can see the POST request going but there is no response and in firebug it displays 'Aborted'.

Comment: I think you have trouble in your server code, check the data which is sent with POST request and response headers.

Comment: An abort status usually comes when there is a timeout. Check the time taken by the server to respond or the timeout set for the AJAX request.

Comment: @VyacheslavVoronchuk: I am using hfs server and static json to respond

Answer (score 0):

Try add to store proxy: `writer:new Ext.data.JsonWriter()`

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
grid.insert(rowIndex,[values])
```